# Ant: Conditional Copy

Tags: ant, conditional-statements

I want to overwrite the hosts file on the Windows machine if the user allows it:

```
<input message="Do you want to overwrite the HOSTS file?"
       addproperty="overwrite.hosts" validargs="yes,no" />

<copy tofile="${env.WINDIR}/system32/drivers/etc/hosts.backup">
    <fileset file="${env.WINDIR}/system32/drivers/etc/hosts" />
</copy>

<copy todir="${env.WINDIR}/system32/drivers/etc">
    <fileset file="${trainer.dir}/hosts" />
</copy>
```

How do I do the copies only if the user says yes?

EDIT:

I tried this:

```
    <input message="Do you want to overwrite the HOSTS file?" addproperty="overwrite.hosts" validargs="yes,no" />

    <if>
        <equals arg1="${overwrite.hosts}" arg2="yes" />
        <then>
            <copy tofile="${env.windir}/system32/drivers/etc/hosts.backup">
                <fileset file="${env.windir}/system32/drivers/etc/hosts">
                </fileset>
            </copy>

            <copy todir="${env.windir}/system32/drivers/etc">
                <fileset file="${trainer.dir}/hosts">
                </fileset>
            </copy>
        </then>
    </if>
```

and I get this output:

```
C:\trainer\build.xml:16: Problem: failed to create task or type if
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
```

I'm an ant rookie... What do I need to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use an "if" parameter on a target to make it conditional on the property being set.

I've never used the "input" task -- I didn't know it existed until just now (thanks for the heads up!) -- but a quick look at the documentation indicates that it sets the named property to the value entered, i.e. after an "input" the property is always set. So I guess you would need a "condition" to test the value and set or not set some other property.

Something like this. I just ran a quick test and this does work. Namely, if you answer the question "y" it prints the message, and if you answer "n" it does not.

```
<project name="test" default="do.whatever">
  <target name="decide.do.whatever">
    <input message="So you wanna do this or not?" validargs="y,n" addproperty="wanna"/>
    <condition property="wanna.yes">
      <equals arg1="${wanna}" arg2="y"/>
    </condition>
  </target>
  <target name="do.whatever" depends="decide.do.whatever" if="wanna.yes">
    <echo message="Yeah he wannas."/>
  </target>
</project>
```

Comment: for this I have to create one more target. That is for every conditional work I have to test it then set property and create new target that will get called on the set property ? Any other way ?

Comment: Yes, exactly, what if you target copies a bunch of different files from different places and you ONLY want to copy some files but not others... you need redundant targets with the same set of tasks, vs condition inside targets to decide which tasks to call or not

Answer (score 9):

You could use a [`condition`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/condition.html) or a [`if` task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/if.html) for that. (The latter is part of the [ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/) project.)

Comment: Not the condition task, actually.

Comment: Haven't used ant for a long time, so I wasn't sure about the nomenclature, but actually in the docs `condition` appeared under tasks (http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/).